# Is there a way to increase the amount of points returned by cv2.findContours?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, computer-vision, contour, image-segmentation

For a project where I try to match jigsaw puzzles, I wrote some code that determines the indentations (inward and outward) of each side of a puzzle. I added two example images showing the result.

[Inward indentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uU3qZ.png)

[Outward indentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfC4m.png)

All indents are detected quite nicely but **the accuracy of it is not always as expected**. I assume this is due to **cv2.findContours()** that only supplies a limited amount of points to work with. I supplied the code of my cv2.findContours().

```
imshape = l.getImageShape(image)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(imshape, 0, 254, 0)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
```

I chose to only use the external lines with RETR_EXTERNAL, since those are the only needed contours. I also decided to save every point with CHAIN_APPROX_NONE, even though I do not really need a lot of info around the straight parts of the side. However, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE also removed some points of the crucial (indentation) part, reducing the accuracy even more.

The first function, getImageShape, simply gets the shape on a similar way to thresh, but I found that I got better results using this in advance instead of just taking the source image as input parameter for the cv2.threshold function in previous code.

```
def getImageShape(img):
    gray   = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray   = cv2.medianBlur(gray, ksize=5)
    thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 254, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
    thresh = cv2.blur(thresh, ksize=(3, 3))
    return thresh
```

Because of the bad accuracy (around 4% inaccuracy of the width/height of a side of the puzzle), matching two sides with eachother only based on their indentation positions results in multiple 'possible' solutions. I was hoping that there was a way to **increase the amount of points** returned by cv2.getContours but have not found any info about it on the openCV documentation.

If this is impossible, I will have to add some image continuity detection algorithm (but this would make it unable to match pieces only by their shape).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i may suggest an alternative:
You can try to make the outlines visible by calculating the image gradient with either a `Sobel` or `Prewitt` filter and use `Canny` edge detection after you did some simple postprocessing.

Here is what i get using that, note that i used the picture you provided with the marker on the outline, so ignore that little inconsistency.

[image: Original]

[image: Sobel]

[image: Postprocessed]

[image: Outlines]

Comment: I tried your code and it was indeed more effective. I also discovered that findContours does in fact return enough points. The problem was that there were multiple adjacent points that were seen as a 'maximum' and my algorithm just took the first one instead of the middle one. Thanks for the help!