# How can i increase the contour points number returned by cv2.findContours in order to calculate the major axis on 3D image?

Tags: python, opencv

I have the contour of an irregular shape using cv2

```
cv2.findContours(img, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
```

and i have calculated the distance between each point of contour in order to determinate the major axis , but the amount of points is small , thus i can't find the correct major axis .
Is there a way to increase  the number of the contour points?

Comment: You might consider using `cv2.connectedcomponents` as it returns all the pixels instead of just the contour pixels.

Comment: This question already exists: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59225138/is-there-a-way-to-increase-the-amount-of-points-returned-by-cv2-findcontours

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to increase the amount of points returned by cv2.findContours?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59225138/is-there-a-way-to-increase-the-amount-of-points-returned-by-cv2-findcontours)

Comment: thank you all for your answers, i already checked that post , but it is for a 2D image while i'm working on 3D image , also i think that the person who answered the question has deleted the solution code because i can't find it .

Comment: @mikeyuri What sort of 3d image do you have? `findContours` takes "an 8-bit single-channel image" as input. How have you tried to calculate the major axis? Image moments should still give you something reasonable even if you only have the contour of the object.

Comment: Post an example image and your code for review.